# User revises approved edit

Tags: support, edits

I edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55184232/7910454) (check the edit history) to make it more readable and my edit got approved. The author, however, decided it was not what he wanted and revised it. I would say *my version* could be described as objectively better but I don't know what to do now.

**Should I**

- redo the edit?
- flag for moderator intervention?
- leave it as is?
- do something else?

I have no clue what I am supposed to do which is why I am asking here. I feel like doing something against it but on the other hand even though you can lead a horse to water, you can't make it drink.

Comment: Fixing just couple spelling mistakes is "marginally better" bordering on "no improvements whatsoever". To really make post better you could have converted "non-working" to reasonable explanation of what is actually happening...

Comment: On my very first question I included an error message that itself contained a typo (occured not occurred). It was edited to correct the spelling, which was clearly inappropriate in terms of the future usefulness of the question. So I corrected it back again. In other words, the OP knows the context, others may or or may not do so. I have been v careful about editing questions myself as a result of this experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a comment asking why the OP rolled back your edit, but there seems little point engaging in a continued to and fro if the OP is simply going to roll back your changes so I wouldn't submit another edit unless the OP says that they made a mistake with the first roll back and promises not to repeat that mistake.

There's nothing for a moderator to do here. The OP can roll back an edit if they want provided that the content they are rolling back to isn't rude or abusive or otherwise not something we want on the site.

Leaving it as it is is also reasonable or you could just downvote the question because it's "unclear or not useful" if you feel that in its current state it fits either of those criteria.

Comment: Note that if reverting the edit substantially defaces or decreases quality of the post, a mod can re-apply the edit and lock the post from further edits, and, in extreme cases, suspend the user. While I'm not sure that's warranted in this case, mods do have options when there are disputes concerning edits.